# Install site-packages inside virtual environment python

Tags: python, django, nginx, virtualenv

I am working on deploying my django application using uwsgi and nginx on a RHEL with pre installed python packages. Server is installed with uwsgi and nginx globally(as root). My server is not connected to internet.

I have secure copied my django project inside this server. For best practices I am told to use virtual environment and when I do the command,

```
virtualenv -p /usr/local/lib/python3.5/bin/python3.5 venv
```

All is cool. It creates a virtual environment with python 3.5.

But the problem is, I need these site packages which is pre installed on the server into this virtual environment. Example django, redis etc. When I do the above command with **--system-site-packages** it throws me this error

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wheel-0.29.0.dist-info'

Is there a cleaner way to do this or where is it going wrong `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
$ pip freeze
```

where pip is the system-wide `pip`. If it outputs anything, then just do:

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt;
$ source /path/to/venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt;
```

In this way you will tell the virtual environment's pip to install all the  python packages that are installed system-wide.

If `pip freeze` doesn't work, this is a privilleges issue, you have to elaborate this as/with an admin.

UPD: You may need to install additional packages as python3-dev, build-essential etc for `pip install -r requirements.txt` to work.

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because of the existence of another user in your machine.Just check if you have the system privileges , if not edit the properties of the file and grant it permission.